# how to prevent the server to close when I close the client socket? C++

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, server, client

I have the following code that is the "server.cpp". It correctly establishes a connection with the client and streams the video. The problem is that when I close the client, regardless of the while cycle in the main program, automatically also the server will shout down, even if I am using pthread_create.

Could you help me to find a solution to avoid it to close, and to remain alive until a new client will connect to it?

```
/**
 * OpenCV video streaming over TCP/IP
 * Server: Captures video from a webcam and send it to a client
 * by Isaac Maia
 */

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>

using namespace cv;

void *display(void *);

int capDev = 0;

VideoCapture cap(capDev); // open the default camera

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

//--------------------------------------------------------
//networking stuff: socket, bind, listen
//--------------------------------------------------------
    int localSocket, remoteSocket, port = 4097;

    struct sockaddr_in localAddr, remoteAddr;
    pthread_t thread_id;

    int addrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    if ((argc > 1) && (strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0))
    {
        std::cerr << "usage: ./cv_video_srv [port] [capture device]\n"
                << "port           : socket port (4097 default)\n"
                << "capture device : (0 default)\n" << std::endl;

        exit(1);
    }

    if (argc == 2)
        port = atoi(argv[1]);

    localSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (localSocket == -1)
    {
        perror("socket() call failed!!");
    }

    localAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    localAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(localSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &localAddr, sizeof(localAddr))
            < 0)
    {
        perror("Can't bind() socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Listening
    listen(localSocket, 3);

    std::cout << "Waiting for connections...\n" << "Server Port:" << port
            << std::endl;

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    while (1)
    {

        //if (remoteSocket < 0) {
        //    perror("accept failed!");
        //    exit(1);
        //}

        remoteSocket = accept(localSocket,
                              (struct sockaddr *) &remoteAddr,
                              (socklen_t*) &addrLen);
        //std::cout << remoteSocket<< "32"<< std::endl;
        if (remoteSocket < 0)
        {
            perror("accept failed!");
            exit(1);
        }
        std::cout << "Connection accepted" << std::endl;
        pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, display, &remoteSocket);

        //pthread_join(thread_id,NULL);

    }
    //pthread_join(thread_id,NULL);
    //close(remoteSocket);

    return 0;
}

void *display(void *ptr)
{
    int socket = *(int *) ptr;
    //OpenCV Code
    //----------------------------------------------------------

    Mat img, imgGray;
    img = Mat::zeros(480, 640, CV_8UC1);
    //make it continuous
    if (!img.isContinuous())
    {
        img = img.clone();
    }

    int imgSize = img.total() * img.elemSize();
    int bytes = 0;
    int key;

    //make img continuos
    if (!img.isContinuous())
    {
        img = img.clone();
        imgGray = img.clone();
    }

    std::cout << "Image Size:" << imgSize << std::endl;

    while (1)
    {

        /* get a frame from camera */
        cap >> img;

        //do video processing here 
        cvtColor(img, imgGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        //send processed image
        if ((bytes = send(socket, imgGray.data, imgSize, 0)) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "bytes = " << bytes << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, i.e. with indentation, and tell us exactly what you mean by 'exit'. Does it crash? Print an error and exit? Exit silently?

Comment: There are fewer closing braces than there are opening ones. Was does `display` do after the loop?

Comment: A step through the disconnect logic with a debugger will probably prove more fruitful to you in the long term than a asking question. Unrelated: `exit(1);` in `main` is kind of pointless `return 1;` will do the job.

Comment: If the thread exits with an exception then it will probably cause the application to terminate. You should run everything in the thread in a try catch block to prevent exceptions escaping. (You should check the documentation of pthread. But any abnormal termination of a thread is likely to cause the application to terminate).

Comment: There is a race condition on your usage of `remoteSocket`

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of reaching the end of a non-`void` function without encountering a `return` statement. `display` is declared to return a `void*`, but doesn't.

Comment: When you have it working. Bring it over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get it reviewed.

Comment: could you please be more precise? Which way shoud I handle the solution? I have also commented the call to pthred_create to see which is the behaviour when a connection has been established and then I will close the client, and in that case the system work properly, but when I enter in display and I will close,also the server close. Could you add some line of code to handle the exception?

Comment: No, could *you* be more precise, and answer all the questions you've been asked?

Comment: the code doesn't give errors. Practically when you type ctrl+c to close the client application, automatically also the server application on the other computer will close at the same time, without errors, simply terminates, as it has reached the end of the program (return 0). I hope I have answered your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `remoteSocket` to `display()` safely, so you have a race condition that could alter the value of `remoteSocket` if another client connects before `display()` has a chance to use the previous value.  Don't pass a pointer to the original `remoteSocket`, pass a copy of it instead.

Also, `display()` is not closing the accepted socket when done using it before exiting, so you are leaking socket descriptors.  Eventually, `accept()` will fail due to lack of available descriptors, and your main loop will exit the program.

Try something more like this instead:

```
/**
 * OpenCV video streaming over TCP/IP
 * Server: Captures video from a webcam and send it to a client
 * by Isaac Maia
 */

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace cv;

void* display(void *);

int capDev = 0;
VideoCapture cap(capDev); // open the default camera

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //networking stuff: socket, bind, listen
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    int localSocket, remoteSocket;
    unsigned short port = 4097;
    struct sockaddr_in localAddr, remoteAddr;
    socklen_t addrLen;

    pthread_t thread_id;    
    int err;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        long lport = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        if ((lport <= 0) || (lport > 65535))
        {
            std::cerr << "usage: ./cv_video_srv [port] [capture device]\n"
                      << "port           : socket port (4097 default)\n"
                      << "capture device : (0 default)\n" << std::endl;

            return 1;
        }

        port = (unsigned short) lport;
    }

    localSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (localSocket == -1)
    {
        perror("socket() call failed");
        return 1;
    }

    localAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    localAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(localSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &localAddr, sizeof(localAddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Can't bind() socket");
        close(localSocket);
        return 1;
    }

    //Listening
    if (listen(localSocket, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("Can't listen() socket");
        close(localSocket);
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Waiting for connections...\n"
              << "Server Port:" << port << std::endl;

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    while (1)
    {
        addrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        remoteSocket = accept(localSocket,
                              (struct sockaddr *) &remoteAddr,
                              &addrLen);
        //std::cout << remoteSocket << std::endl;
        if (remoteSocket < 0)
        {
            perror("accept failed");
            close(localSocket);
            return 1;
        }

        std::cout << "Connection accepted" << std::endl;

        int *socket = new int(remoteSocket);
        err = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, display, socket);
        if (err != 0)
        {
            //perror("pthread_create failed");
            std::cerr << "pthread_create failed: " << strerror(err) << std::endl;
            close(remoteSocket);
            delete socket;
            continue;
        }

        //pthread_join(thread_id,NULL);
    }

    //pthread_join(thread_id,NULL);

    return 0;
}

void* display(void *ptr)
{
    int socket = * (int*) ptr;
    delete (int*) ptr;

    //OpenCV Code
    //----------------------------------------------------------

    Mat img, imgGray;
    img = Mat::zeros(480, 640, CV_8UC1);
    //make it continuous
    if (!img.isContinuous())
    {
        img = img.clone();
    }

    int imgSize = img.total() * img.elemSize();
    int bytes = 0;
    int key;

    //make img continuos
    if (!img.isContinuous())
    {
        img = img.clone();
        imgGray = img.clone();
    }

    std::cout << "Image Size:" << imgSize << std::endl;

    while (1)
    {
        /* get a frame from camera */
        cap >> img;

        //do video processing here 
        cvtColor(img, imgGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        //send processed image
        bytes = send(socket, imgGray.data, imgSize, 0);
        if (bytes <= 0)
        {
            if (bytes < 0)
                perror("send failed");
            break;
        }
    }

    close(socket);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: this solution is not working... I have found that if I use the flag MSG_NOSIGNAL instead of 0 in the call ¨send¨ of function display the program doesn´t close... the problem is that when I try to reconnect the client, the program will remain stucked just before the while(1) in funcntion display

Comment: @F.DEVIVO: See [Prevent a process from terminating when writing to a broken pipe](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/prevent_a_process_from_terminating_when_writing_to_a_broken_pipe.html). But either way you disable `SIGPIPE`, `send()` will simply fail with an error code on disconnect, which this code already handles to terminate the thread loop. It can't get stuck in the loop unless `send()` is reporting success. When the client disconnects, the loop should break. When the client reconnects, a new thread should be starting.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for taking too late to the answer.

Your problem is in this line:

```
send(socket, imgGray.data, imgSize, 0);
```

According to [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html), `send` signs a `SIGPIPE` signal:

> SIGPIPE signal if the peer on a stream-oriented socket has closed the
> connection

and according to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Operation-Error-Signals.html)

> The default action ... is to cause the process to terminate.

The solution is using `MSG_NOSIGNAL` such as

```
send(socket, imgGray.data, imgSize, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

> MSG_NOSIGNAL is a per-call feature, ignoring SIGPIPE sets a process attribute that affects all threads in the process.

You can detect that this error occurred by checking if the EPIPE error returned. More details about this can be found in the mentioned docs.